# sort and display documents based on industry which is fetched from each entity

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an .xml file which is structured as such:

```
<documents>
<item>
    <title>Document Title</title>
    <customer>Customer Name1</customer>
    <description>Description 1 here</description>
    <image height="100" width="100"></image>
    <link filetype="pdf" language="English">/documents/document.pdf</link>
    <industry>Industry name 1</industry>
</item>
<item>
    <title>Document Title 2</title>
    <customer>Customer Name 2</customer>
    <description>Description 2 here</description>
    <image height="100" width="100"></image>
    <link filetype="pdf" language="English">/documents/document2.pdf</link>
    <industry>Industry name 2</industry>
</item>
```

What I need this to become, preferrably using XSL (as I know a bit about it already and I'd catch on quickly), is this:

```
<h2>Industry name 1</h2>
<div class="doc">
<h3>Document Title</h3>
<p>Description 1 here <a href="/documents/document.pdf">Download!</a></p>
</div>

<h2>Industry name 2</h2>
<div class="doc">
<h3>Document Title 2</h3>
<p>Description 2 here <a href="/documents/document.pdf">Download!</a></p>
</div>
```

Where I am completely stumped, is how I could dynamically get the industries from within the XML, print the first one and then all documents relating to that industry, and then move on to the second industry, then the third, and fourth and so on. Where I start to wonder if this even possible, is when I consider that the XSL has to actually store each industry "tag" from each  and compare them in order to see if it already has it. If it does, it should not print it, but simply print the rest of the information.

I would rather avoid changing the schema of the XML file, as it's in use all over the place already serving other purposes. But, I realize it might have to be.

Please also note that the file is completely unsorted. Latest file added is at the top, regardless of industry "tag" associated with it. This can be changed however.

To me, this is a tough nut to crack, if it even can be using pure XSL as a parser?

Comment: Do you want to group documents by industry?

Comment: @empo Yes, they need to be grouped and have the industry name in the h2 tag above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kItemByInd" match="item"
  use="industry"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "item[generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kItemByInd', industry)[1])
       ]
  ">
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="industry"/></h2>

  <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"
   select="key('kItemByInd', industry)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item"/>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="inGroup">
   <div class="doc">
     <h3><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h3>
     <p>
       <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
       <a href="{link}"> Download!</a>
     </p>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (obtained from the provided one by adding one more item -- to make it more interesting):

```
<documents>
    <item>
        <title>Document Title</title>
        <customer>Customer Name1</customer>
        <description>Description 1 here</description>
        <image height="100" width="100"></image>
        <link filetype="pdf" language="English">/documents/document.pdf</link>
        <industry>Industry name 1</industry>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Document Title 2</title>
        <customer>Customer Name 2</customer>
        <description>Description 2 here</description>
        <image height="100" width="100"></image>
        <link filetype="pdf" language="English">/documents/document2.pdf</link>
        <industry>Industry name 2</industry>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Document Title 3</title>
        <customer>Customer Name 3</customer>
        <description>Description 3 here</description>
        <image height="100" width="100"></image>
        <link filetype="pdf" language="English">/documents/document3.pdf</link>
        <industry>Industry name 1</industry>
    </item>
</documents>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<h2>Industry name 1</h2>
<div class="doc">
   <h3>Document Title</h3>
   <p>Description 1 here<a href="/documents/document.pdf"> Download!</a>
   </p>
</div>
<div class="doc">
   <h3>Document Title 3</h3>
   <p>Description 3 here<a href="/documents/document3.pdf"> Download!</a>
   </p>
</div>

<h2>Industry name 2</h2>
<div class="doc">
   <h3>Document Title 2</h3>
   <p>Description 2 here<a href="/documents/document2.pdf"> Download!</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

**and it displays in the browser as**:

### Industry name 1

#### Document Title

Description 1 here [Download!](/documents/document.pdf)

#### Document Title 3

Description 3 here [Download!](/documents/document3.pdf)

### Industry name 2

#### Document Title 2

Description 2 here [Download!](/documents/document2.pdf)

**Explanation**: **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml)**.

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="industry">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="industry"/></h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
   <div class="doc">
     <h3><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h3>
     <p>
       <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
       <a href="{link}"> Download!</a>
     </p>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the same correct result is produced**.

**Explanation**:

1. [**`<xsl:for-each-group>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-for-each-group)
2. [**`current-group()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#dt-current-group)

**UPDATE**: As per OP's request, here is a variation of the XSLT 1.0 solution, that also sorts by `industry`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kItemByInd" match="item"
  use="industry"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "item[generate-id()
        =
         generate-id(key('kItemByInd', industry)[1])
        ]
   ">
    <xsl:sort select="industry"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="industry"/></h2>

  <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"
   select="key('kItemByInd', industry)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="inGroup">
   <div class="doc">
     <h3><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h3>
     <p>
       <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
       <a href="{link}"> Download!</a>
     </p>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome! I couldn't get the seemingly simpler 2.0 version to work, but the 1.0 way worked fine. Is it also possible to sort the industries by alphabet? Usually I'd just add an xsl:sort, but that won't go in a template, so is there another way of doing that?

Comment: @Patrik Alienus: To run XSLT 2.0 transformations you need to have an XSLT 2.0 processor. In case you are just starting XSLT I'd strongly recommend to embrace XSLT 2.0 from the very beginning. As for sorting by industry, yes, this can be done, but then in the first solution we must have an explicit `<xsl:apply-templates>` with `<xsl:sort>` as a child. With the second solution -- just add an `<xsl:sort>` child to `<xsl-for-each-group>`.

Comment: Yes I would like to use 2.0, unfortunately I can't because of server constraints. However, what do you mean by an "explicit" `<xsl:apply-templates>`? I noticed that simply adding the `<xsl:sort>` to the `<xsl:template match="item" mode="inGroup">` did not work... So I guess my real question is, where does the explicit `<xsl:apply-templates>` go?

Comment: @Patrik Alienus: I have updated my answer (look at the very end) with a variation of the XSLT 1.0 solution, which also sorts the groups by `industry`